# Custom Home Screen for Google/Nest Hub

Tags: google-home

I would like to setup a custom dashboard on the Home Screen of my Nest Hub to display selected stock prices, air quality, COVID stats, or whatever else is of most interest to me and fits on one screen. I haven’t found anything out of the box that would do this, so assume I will have to develop that myself.

Questions:

- Has anybody done this, is there installable apps or sample code?
- Are there APIs that let you create a custom display on the Home Screen?
- If nothing else works, I would write an external script such as
  Google Apps Script that runs every minute or so, pulls all
  information from various REST APIs, renders a JPEG with text and
  charts on it, uploads it to Google Photos, and this picture is my
  Home Screen. Any reason why this shouldn’t work?

Comment: any luck so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am blocked by Google Photos API not allowing service account authentication (https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/authorization). So a continuously running backend service cannot upload pictures to it, only a session with a real authenticated user.
Any other ideas? I recently saw a comparison between Amazon Echo display and Nest Hub where Nest was called out for not doing web browsing. This would also solve my issue.

Comment: I found a work around. You can cast web pages on all your chrome cast devices including nest hub. Check out this [repo](https://github.com/skorokithakis/catt). People also suggest to send a feedback from the home app (from the devise section) to get Google's attention.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is no widget support and also no information if this will be added in the near future.

I found a work around. You can cast anything, including webpages, to any of your Chrome Cast devices. Check out [CATT repo](https://github.com/skorokithakis/catt). There is also a [discussion](https://www.domoticz.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30644) on the domoticz forum.

People also suggest to send a feedback from the home app (from the nest hub section) to get Google's attention. But there have been no updates on the topic since 2018.